# windows 7 path not set by install until after reboot

Tags: windows, installation, environment-variables

We have a third party driver tool that sets a path to their DLLs during installation. On a standard user account in 64-bit Windows 7, the new path is not applied until after reboot or logging off/on.

Apparently the path is set at elevated privileges. If I run a DOS box as administrator then the new path is there. If not then not.

Seems kind of silly to have to reboot since the new path gets applied anyway.  Why should we have to reboot just for that?

Does anyone know any way to apply the new path to the standard user without rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [broadcast the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497(v=vs.85).aspx) with lParam set to the string "Environment".

Note that generally speaking the only application that actually pays attention to this is Windows Explorer, so it will usually only affect applications that are launched from Windows Explorer after the change has been made.  For example, existing command-line windows will not be affected.

Comment: I saw that answer elsewhere but do not see how it will help. 

Suppose we send WM_SETTINGCHANGE after the installation.  Now launch a normal DOS box.  Since it is not elevated there there will be no new path.  Next launch new elevated DOS box.  New path is set. Since neither of these DOS boxes was running when WM_SETTINGCHANGE was posted how does that help?

Seems like this is a privilege problem.

Comment: If the problem goes away when you reboot, it has nothing to do with privileges.  I'm guessing that when you start an elevated command line you're putting in the username and password each time; that starts a new logon session, so it gets the new environment variables. It doesn't matter that the command line interpreter wasn't running when WM_SETTINGCHANGE was broadcast, because Explorer was running, and that's what new processes inherit from.

Comment: I see.  When we start an elevated command we simply right click Command Prompt, Run as Administrator.  No username/password entered. Where then does the new environment come from?

Comment: OK, I can confirm that new elevated processes always get an fresh set of environment variables even when elevation occurs silently.  Following the sequence of events with Process Monitor this appears to be deliberate, perhaps as a security measure or perhaps for consistency with the case when you are authenticating to a different account.  Note that Explorer could just as easily do this every time it launches a non-elevated process (but doesn't).

Comment: If you're still suspicious that this may be related to privilege, a simple experiment would be to turn off UAC altogether.  That way all processes (including Explorer) run with full privilege but no elevation is involved.